Render Freestyle Edge as Alpha layer
Simple animation that has edge layers on one object, but I want to render the Freestyle edge as a separate alpha layer so I can control the transparency. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

You could achieve that with View Layers : render another layer only with the edges and composite as you want. Did you try that ? Your question lacks context to give an exact answer.

Im not sure how else to explain. I have freestyle edge visible in the full render, but I want to have it as a separate render with only the edge visible, but it needs to be an alpha layer so when I make my video i can control the layer transparency.

Then use layers and convert your edge layer to an alpha layer in your editing software.
